# What is the advantage of using header-catname.php over is_category('catname');?

Tags: categories, customization, headers, custom-header

Let's say I have a category named as `catname` (the slug would be `catname`). I want the header styled differently when visitors open the category catname.

The [article on Ghacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/24/wordpress-customer-headers-for-categories/) explains how to create a custom header (styled differently) when visitors open the category catname, achieved by creating header-catname.php and including it in category-catname.php with `include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-catname.php');`  (instead of the usual `get_header();` ). You can read the short article itself if my explanations is difficult to follow (I apologize for my lack of proficient English).

My question is: what is the advantage of using above method, over using `is_category ('catname')` in header.php to create custom header only for the catname category?

I mean, in the header.php we could just use this without creating additional header-catname.php:

```
 <?php if ( is_category('catname') ) { ?>

 /* Insert custom header for category catname here */

 <?php } else { ?>

 /* Insert the usual header here */

 <?php } ?>
```

Does using the conditional IF make the page load slower? Or is there any disadvantage?

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? :/ I don't think it's similar to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/any-advantage-to-using-get-header-over-includeheader-php?rq=1 , because I'm comparing it with the IF conditional. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article on Ghacks is actually a pretty silly way to do it as well.

The `get_header()` function is actually a pretty smart function. You can do some neat things with it. For example, you can do this:

`get_header('category');`

That will cause it to load the header-category.php file, if such a file exists, or the header.php file, if header-category.php does not exist.

Here's a cool way to make use of that property:

```
if (is_category()) {
  $cat = get_queried_object();
  get_header($cat->name);
}
```

This will cause it to load header-catname.php, using the actual category name, with a fallback to header.php if such a file does not exist.

If you want, you can even extend that to be more generic and work for any taxonomy:

```
if ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {
  $term = get_queried_object();
  get_header($term->name);
}
```

Lots of neat things you can do with those template fallbacks.

Comment: Whoa interesting, I didn't know about `get_header('category')`, seems to be lot more effective thant the way provided in Ghacks. I assume this works with get_footer, get_sidebar,etc too?

Comment: Yup, footer and sidebar work the same way.

Comment: Is there any differences in speed or execution process between using the `get_header('catname');` and `include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-catname.php');`?

Comment: Not really, no. They basically do the same thing, but get_header is more future-proof.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer! Would like to upvote both answers but still not enough point for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches a almost equal. Access to the file system is always slower than plain PHP execution in a file.

If your extra code is short put it into the same file. If it rather long separate it to keep the default code readable. Execution time is not the only, and often not the most important, criterion. Maintainability counts too, especially when you have to fix something really fast.

A real advantage of separate files: A child theme can override just that specific file.

Comment: I see... is there any other advantage besides maintainability?

Comment: See my edit (last sentence).