# What's stopping my HTML from rendering in my template parts?

Tags: theme-development, html

I just started building a custom theme so I only have the core files with a `header.php` and `footer.php` file.
So far all I've done in my `functions.php` file is enqueue my css and js so I haven't added any theme support for anything.
So far my files look like this:

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>
    
    
    <header class="testB">
        <p>header section</p>
    </header>
```

**footer.php**

```
    <footer>
        <p>footer</p>
        
    </footer>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<p class="test">body</p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So far the only markup that displays is the `<p>body</p>` in the `index.php` file.
I studied the code to the twentytwentyone theme and don't see anything that particularly appears to enable the ability for our markup to render.
I haven't created any other template parts yet besides the header and footer.
The only thing I'm doing differently is instead of having the header and footer in the root directory I have them in a folder called `framework` and in their respective folders.
So for example the path to the header from the root directory is `framework/header/header.php`.

Is there a WP standard that says that has to be in the root directory?

I come from an Angular background so I prefer to sort every tiny chunk of code into their own folders and sub folders.
Can any of you spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You would need to use `require` or `get_template_part` to get the `header.php` if its inside a folder/sub-folder. WordPress searches `header.php`, `footer.php` and a few others in the root of your theme and no where else.

Answer (score -1):

`get_header()` will load `wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/header.php` by default.
If you want to grab other php file use

```php
<?php require_once 'framework/header/header.php'; ?>
```

Other way is using **get_template_part**

Then use following code anywhere you want

```php
<?= get_template_part('framework/header/header') ?>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `require_once`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have to disagree. It would be better to have a wordpress error if, for some reason `header.php` is not available than seeing a broken site. Sense `header.php` contains the opening `doctype` and `wp_head()` and many other meta, script, styles pixles etc... there would be no point showing the site without them.

Comment: The correct way to load templates in WordPress is `get_template_part()`. `require_once`, as used in this answer is also not compatible with child themes. Not to mention that header.php being missing would be very obvious without needing to use the wrong function. There's no circumstances where header.php should go missing anyway. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5195/39152

Comment: @JacobPeattie why not?
i've never used child theme so what's wrong with it?

Comment: Because `get_template_part()` uses functions to check child themes for templates first. `require_once` is a PHP expression that doesn't take any of that into account. You could combine `require_once` with functions for finding templates, but this answer doesn't do that, and there's no point if `get_template_part()` already does it. Additionally `get_template_part()` and `require_once` handle variable scoping differently which could lead to unexpected results.